# How can I record audio from an MP3 player into my Mac?

Tags: audio, recording, record

so I use a portable audio recorder to record interviews, but it’s microusb port broke (but everything else work), I can still record new files and play the recordings from the built in speaker and 3.5mm audio input jack.

The problem is that I can no longer connect it to my computer and copy the recordings, even though I got the microusb replaced, it just charges but no data transfer is recognized by any computer.

How can I record those files into my Mac? First idea that came to my mind was to reproduce the audios on the portable recorder built in speakers and connect a microphone into my computer so it records the audio but I think this is not the best method to go.

Is there a program that I  can use to connect a 3.5mm to 3.5mm cable to both my computer and the recorder and record the audio?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Surely the portable recorder has a micro SD card? I would remove the Micro SD card and then use an SD card adapter and reader to transfer the files.

If this is not the case or you cannot remove the SD card for whatever reason, there are any number of voice recorder apps in the App Store you can try.

I would also be checking that the cable isn't faulty. Try a different cable before giving up on the Micro USB connection.

Comment: Thanks, the recorder has a built in memory, so no SD card. I've also tried with different USB cables. For the other suggestion, I would like to record the audio using an audio cable rather than the speakers and a microphone.

Comment: OK so grab a USB Audio interface from ebay - they are dirt cheap. This will give you a clean Line Input, to which you need to connect the audio output from your recorder with a 3.5mm to 3.5mm cable. Recording software is available on the OSX App Store. That should do you.